# MySQL query a query and return a count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One called HOSTS and one called GUESTS.
The **HOSTS** table consists of:

```
* hid
* firstname
* lastname
* email
```

**hid** is the unique Host Identifier which is an INTEGER, primary key and auto-incremented.

The **GUESTS** table consists of:

```
* gid
* hid
* gfname
* glname
```

**gid** is the unique Guest Identifier which is an INTEGER, primary key and auto-incremented.

The desired output is to show on each row the HOSTS and a sum total (figure) of guests each host has.

firstname lastname email "tot num of guests"

How do one accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Join* the tables and then *group* the results:

```
SELECT   HOSTS.*, COUNT(gid)
FROM     HOSTS LEFT JOIN GUESTS USING (hid)
GROUP BY hid
```

Comment: Can I ask for an even more advance query here or should I create a new question?

Comment: @Andreas: You should really ask a new question.

Comment: I've created a new post. Hopefully you can help me out with that one too